# Does power bi paginated report support SSO to SSAS?

Tags: powerbi

I'm exploring power bi paginated reports.

It does support SSAS via the gateway, but it doesn't mention SSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-data-sources#other-data-sources

Does power bi paginated report support SSO to SSAS? That is - can I pass the viewers identity to the SSAS so that for exmaple the RLS (in SSAS) can be utilized?

Answer (score 1):

Should work like any other [gateway connection to SSAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas), where you configure the Windows credentials of an SSAS admin in the Power BI Service, and then pass the end-user identityusing EffectiveUserName or Customdata.

[image]